# MSpec on Appharbor

Tags: .net, unit-testing, continuous-integration, mspec, appharbor

It it possible to execute [mspec](https://github.com/machine/machine.specifications) tests on [appharbor](https://appharbor.com) aside from adding build action ?

Comment: AppHarbor uses Gallio to run unit tests. There's a mspec plugin for Gallio, but I'm not 100% sure it's installed on our build servers. Could I get you to give it a try, and if it doesn't work, drop us a line (at support@appharbor.com) so that we can add support for it?

Comment: Gallio has no default support for mspec. But mspec provides a plugin for gallio...

Comment: So did you manage to get them run?

Comment: No, didn't have time on it :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is now possible to run Machine.Specifications (MSpec) tests on AppHarbor.

Comment: How: Just add MSpec tests to your solution.
Why: MSpec was not installed on the build servers.

I don't know if it still works, as I do not work at AppHarbor anymore. And don't use MSpec.

Comment: Mmmm, not always that easy @niels. AppHarbor only supports some versions of Machine.Specifications. This page shows only some older versions of mspec: http://support.appharbor.com/kb/getting-started/running-unit-tests-after-build